# Dropdownlist JSP + EJB + Servlet Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have a proyect JSP EJB Servlet then I must fill data from my SQL table `city` to the dropdownlist into `index.jsp`. This is my code from the `index.jsp` but, i can't insert the cities into `<option>` my project.

Please, could you help me?

```
<select name="ciudad">
                        <option>Selecciona ciudad...</option>
                        <c:forEach items="${ciudades}" var="ciudad" >
                            <option>
                                ${ciudad.idCiudad}
                            </option>
                        </c:forEach>
        </select><br/>


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Ciudad> ciudad = new ArrayList<Ciudad>();
    try {
        ciudad = CiudadService.findAll();
    } catch (ServicioException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        Logger.getLogger(CiudadListController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    request.setAttribute("ciudades", ciudad );
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/listadoCiudades.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

I'm using Pool connection by Glashfish

This is my method findAll from PostulanteService.java

```
public List<Postulante> findAll() throws ServicioException{

    List<Postulante> list = null;
    try{
        list = em.
            createNamedQuery("Postulante.findAll",Postulante.class).getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException ex) {
        throw new ServicioException("No existen resultados");
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `CiudadService.findAll()` returns non-empty list?

Comment: this is my code from CiudadService.findAll()
public List<Postulante> findAll() throws ServicioException{
        
        List<Postulante> list = null;
        try{
            list = em.
                createNamedQuery("Postulante.findAll",Postulante.class).getResultList();
        } catch (NoResultException ex) {
            throw new ServicioException("No existen resultados");
        }
        return list;
    }

Comment: It's better put your code in your original question. And you didn't answer mine :)

Comment: I'm not sure if my method findAll(), returns non-empty list. i'm Sorry but my english is not very good :(

Comment: @BalusC, I'm not a web developer, I just want to learn programming and had a question about it. I think you may have been a bit more friendly or help a little. Finally, I solved this problem elsewhere. Thank you very much to those who took the time to read this post.